# PS Vita doesn't wake back up

Tags: ps-vita

I'm having  problems with my Vita not waking back up from a long sleep. I play my Vita for a few mins a day and then leave it sleep/charging for long periods (I never turn any of my hardware off).

I was talking to a few buddies online and 2 of them out of a few that have it, said they experience the same thing where they let it go sleep and when they come back, the units "PSlog button" stays lit (sometimes not) and they have to do a hard reboot.

After the hard reboot, the unit comes up with some restore options etc. we press the restore option and once you hit that, system reboots, does its thing and all is well.

This doesn't seem like normal behavior for the unit so I'm wondering if anyone has experienced this and if so, if you've found a solution, or is my unit (and friends units) defective?

Comment: have you found a solution to your issue yet?  I've had my Vita freeze on me once so far

Comment: Honestly, im not 100% sure but i THINK so...someone told me that, they were having similar problems and when they turned off their ATNT connection (the 3g version btw) that it stopped the problem for them...that the system froze when the system tried to switch from 3g/wifi....now i dont know the validity of this claim BUT...i turned of my 3g since i dont use it and it hasnt frozen since lol so....you can try that. If you have a regular wifi version then i dont know lol. Good luck

Comment: Is this a 3G or a Wifi version? If you have a 3G version and you haven't signed up for AT&T's service, that can cause problems for the system and you'll want to shut off the mobile network in settings. Also, some apps periodically connect out when the device is shut off, so the culprit could be one of the programs you've downloaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've experienced this issue a few times. The only way to fix it is to hold the power button down for 10-15 seconds until the unit turns off and and reboots. From the recovery menu select option 1 (reboot) to load the system as normal. It only takes 30 seconds to fix so not a big issue.

Unfortunately, I haven't identified the cause of the issue. It happens randomly, probably when it tries to connect to the internet (hence flashing blue lights) and crashes.

Comment: yep thats what i been doing, not a true resolution but...least it wakes back up lol